# How to make a ListBox have a max width?

Tags: asp.net, listbox

I am having trouble with this list box, as it gets populated the width grows with each new selection. I would like to set it to a max width so it doesn't grow huge and make the page unusable.

```
<td><asp:ListBox ID="lstLocations" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" DataTextField="Label" DataValueField="value"></asp:ListBox></td>
```

Comment: Use CSS: `#lstLocations { max-width: 300px; }`.

Comment: I tried this but the list box still grows as it is populated